# I try to parse internal network webpage using by beautifulsoup library but didn't same like html

Tags: python, html, parsing

I'd like to make an auto login program in internal network website.

So, I try to parse that site using requests and Beautifulsoup library.

It works...and I get some html alot shorter than that site's html.

what's the problem? maybe security issue?..

pleas help me.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

page = requests.get("http://test.com")
soup = bs(page.text, "html.parse")
print(soup) # I get some html alot shorter than that site's html
```

Comment: What is the difference between the HTMLs? Perhaps you need to be logged in, or it is serving a lightweight version because you omit some headers.

Comment: The html showed on the web browser is very long and detailed but the other html that I parsing by python is very short and summarized. I don't know why the two html are different. thank you for your answer!

Comment: Use the developer console of your browser to see the headers your browser is sending along with the request. Add them one by one until you get the right HTML response.